# Unreal Engine and Simple Animation

Tags: animation, unreal-4, blueprints

I am creating a card based game and I am stuck on an animation detail.
My question is I need an animation to shuffle the deck, a animation for dealing and  an animation for drawing.
My question is should I create the animations in Unreal Engine or would I create them in blender. I know traditionally with characters and other animations you would create them within blender. However I am unsure in this instance as we are talking about simply shuffling, dealing, and drawing cards.

Comment: How the animations should look like ? - dealing for instance could be just a "tweening" animations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that should not make much of a difference you obviously can import animations from blender so that wont be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with unreal, animation/modeling and simple, I think you could use it.

Especially if you are going to do a simple animation (just moving the cards with simple moves).

Now if you want something more refined, with the cards rotating on some axis, I think it would be easier for the blender. Because I believe that if you need help you will find it easier, both here in the forum and on youtube.